# Which is the best way to work with NCBI data obtaining online partial information from the whole

Tags: programming, python, biology

I was trying to create a database from NCBI Nucleotide bank. I did a query which gave me 1124 results.
From each single result I was wanting to obtain only the items realted to  `Accesion` `Country` and `isolation`.

Here is what I get from the NCBI

`LOCUS       MH973850                 410 bp    DNA     linear   PLN 03-MAR-2019
DEFINITION  Cryptococcus neoformans isolate OA2 internal transcribed spacer 1,
            partial sequence; 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, complete sequence; and
            internal transcribed spacer 2, partial sequence.
ACCESSION   MH973850
VERSION     MH973850.1
KEYWORDS    .
SOURCE      Cryptococcus neoformans
  ORGANISM  Cryptococcus neoformans
            Eukaryota; Fungi; Dikarya; Basidiomycota; Agaricomycotina;
            Tremellomycetes; Tremellales; Cryptococcaceae; Cryptococcus;
            Cryptococcus neoformans species complex.
REFERENCE   1  (bases 1 to 410)
  AUTHORS   Abaci Gunyar,O., Yoltas,A., Haliki Uztan,A. and Yamac,M.
  TITLE     Isolation and Identification of Cryptococcus neoformans from the
            soil samples taken from inside and outside of Nigde Duzkir (=
            Aladaglar) cave
  JOURNAL   Unpublished
REFERENCE   2  (bases 1 to 410)
  AUTHORS   Abaci Gunyar,O., Yoltas,A., Haliki Uztan,A. and Yamac,M.
  TITLE     Direct Submission
  JOURNAL   Submitted (24-SEP-2018) Biology, Ege University, Genclik Caddesi,
            Izmir 35040, Turkiye
COMMENT     ##Assembly-Data-START##
            Sequencing Technology :: Sanger dideoxy sequencing
            ##Assembly-Data-END##
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..410
                     /organism="Cryptococcus neoformans"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /isolate="OA2"
                     /isolation_source="Soil sample"
                     /db_xref="taxon:5207"
     misc_RNA        <1..>410
                     /note="contains internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S
                     ribosomal RNA, and internal transcribed spacer 2"
ORIGIN

        1 aggatcagta gagaatattg gacttcggtc catttatcta cccatctaca cctgtgaact
       61 gtttatgtgc ttcggcacgt tttacacaaa cttctaaatg taatgaatgt aatcttatta
      121 taacaataat aaaactttca acaacggatc tcttggcttc cacatcgatg aagaacgcag
      181 cgaaatgcga taagtaatgt gaattgcaga attcagtgaa tcatcgaatc tttgaacgca
      241 acttgcgccc tttggtattc cgaagggcat gcctgtttga gagtcatgaa aatctcaatc
      301 cctcgggttt tattacctgt tggacttgga tttgggtgtt tgccgcgacc tgcaaaggac
      361 gtcggctcgc cttaaatgtg ttagtgggaa ggtgattacc tgtcagcccg
//`

What I want to **obtain** from the whole data

`VERSION`**MH973850.1**

`JOURNAL   Submitted (24-SEP-2018) Biology, Ege University, Genclik Caddesi,
            Izmir 35040,`**Turkiye**

`FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..410
                     /organism="Cryptococcus neoformans"
                     /mol_type="genomic DNA"
                     /isolate="OA2"
                     /`**isolation_source="Soil sample**"
                     `/db_xref="taxon:5207"
     misc_RNA        <1..>410
                     /note="contains internal transcribed spacer 1, 5.8S
                     ribosomal RNA, and internal transcribed spacer 2"`

Which is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python3 code snippet that users the [biopython](https://biopython.org/) library:

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = 'test@test.com'
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term="Cryptococcus neoformans isolate OA2 internal transcribed spacer 1") # generates URL
record = Entrez.read(handle) # requests entity ids
id_list = record.get('IdList',None)

for x in id_list:
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=x, retmode="xml") # makes query for each ID, returns XML format

    record = Entrez.read(handle) # parses XML format
    # print (record[0]) # print entire result (python dict)

    # this is parsing some fields you need
    print ('accession:',record[0].get('GBSeq_primary-accession',None))
    for item in record[0].get('GBSeq_feature-table',None)[0].get('GBFeature_quals',None):
        for k in item.keys():
            print (k, ':',item.get(k))
```

prints

```
accession: MH973850
GBQualifier_name : organism
GBQualifier_value : Cryptococcus neoformans
GBQualifier_name : mol_type
GBQualifier_value : genomic DNA
GBQualifier_name : isolate
GBQualifier_value : OA2
GBQualifier_name : isolation_source
GBQualifier_value : Soil sample
GBQualifier_name : db_xref
GBQualifier_value : taxon:5207
```

You'll have to finish the code yourself to get the exact keys/values you need. I didn't see any "country" field, except the journal publication locale.

If you don't use the code, at least use the `retmode='XML'` so you can easily parse the response.